# How do I make vim's method jump commands ']]' and '[[' work with modern method syntax?

Tags: vim

If I use old-school curly brace function block syntax like so:

```
function()
{
  console.log('this works :)');
}
```

I can jump between methods quickly with vim's `]]` and `[[` commands, but if I (or anybody else on my team) use the more modern syntax where the opening curly brace is in-line with the function signature like so:

```
function() {
  console.log('this doesn't work :(');
}
```

Vim won't detect the method and will skip it because the command only looks for opening braces on the first column.  How can I configure Vim to not ignore this syntax?

I'm not against using either syntax but I don't want to skip over methods when reading other peoples' code.

Comment: Try `:help [m` and `:help ]m`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation, there's a part that reply to your question :

[Vim wikia jump to the start and end of a code block](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Jumping_to_the_start_and_end_of_a_code_block)

if you type ":h [[" in vim and then search for "map", you'll find the response

```
If your '{' or '}' are not in the first column, and you would like to use "[["
and "]]" anyway, try these mappings: >
   :map [[ ?{<CR>w99[{
   :map ][ /}<CR>b99]}
   :map ]] j0[[%/{<CR>
   :map [] k$][%?}<CR>
[type these literally, see |<>|]
```

Comment: I somehow missed this after staring at that exact page for 10 minutes.  Thanks.

Comment: For anyone else wondering, these will NOT work as `nnoremap` commands since the second two rely on the first two to function properly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for a great answer @MisterBanal

I was able to improve on the above, so that the search context is preserved and ]] [[ will never wrap around.

```
function s:SetSrchReg(s, w)
    let @/ = a:s
    let &wrapscan = a:w
endfunction
function s:ProtectSrchReg(map)
    " echomsg "ProtectSrchReg "..a:map
    let srchSave = @/
    let wsSave = &wrapscan
    set nowrapscan
    exe timer_start(50, {-> s:SetSrchReg(srchSave, wsSave)})
    return a:map
endfunction

nnoremap <expr> <silent> [[ <SID>ProtectSrchReg('?{<CR>w99[{')
nnoremap <expr> <silent> ][ <SID>ProtectSrchReg('/}<CR>b99]}')
nnoremap <expr> <silent> ]] <SID>ProtectSrchReg('/{<CR>?{<CR>j099[{%/{<CR>')
nnoremap <expr> <silent> [] <SID>ProtectSrchReg('k$99]}%?}<CR>')
```